BTC transfer fees from binance wallet to another wallet
I am new to crypto and I didn't know about transaction fees.
This is the issue I am facing:
I have bought 20 USD in BTC (0.0003) from Binance and I want to transfer it to another wallet but it's asking for a large amount of this around 5 or 6 usd as transfer fees.
I have 6 questions (The first 2 are the ones related to my issue):
1-Is there a cheaper way to transfer BTC from 1 wallet to another ? If yes how to do it with steps in Binance please.
2-If let's say I am transferreing 40 USD of BTC will the transfer fees be less or the same as the 20 USD (5 or 6 USD)?

3-Which BTC wallets are the most secure private and are open source?
4-What is the best way to buy crypto without KYC ?
5-What are the best course(s) to learn the basics of crypto in general and have a solid foundation of knowlege ?
6-How to buy monero ?
Thanks in advance

This site works best when you ask one question at a time, I suggest you edit the question to focus on one issue that is currently the most important for you.


Is there a cheaper way to transfer BTC from 1 wallet to another?

The bitcoin network has transaction fees (but does not have transfer fees). Transaction fees are effectively your bid in an auction of space in the next page of the online book of transactions called the blockchain. A complicated transaction takes more space in that page (block).
Choosing a high transaction-fee will get your transaction confirmed (i.e processed) faster.
Choosing a low transaction-fee will mean your transaction may take longer or may never get confirmed.
Many Bitcoin wallets help you set the fee appropriate to current level of activity in the Bitcoin network.
There are also websites that show current fee-rates for various desired confirmation times.

https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+fee+rate+calculator+OR+estimator



If yes how to do it with steps in Binance please.

If you have problems using a service provided by a business it is best to contact the customer support service of that business directly yourself. Readers contributing answers to this self-help question&answer website generally have no special insight into the internal workings of any of the thousands of businesses that offer services related  in some way to Bitcoin.

https://www.binance.com/en/support
https://www.binance.com/en-GB/support/faq/crypto-withdrawal-fees-on-binance-d9ff84dccc24423cbe6d59859d86afe3

Binance's FAQ says

Since transaction fees are dynamic, you will be charged according to the current network conditions. The fee amount is based on an estimate of the network transaction fees and can fluctuate without notice due to factors such as network congestion. Please check the most updated fee displayed on the withdrawal page.

This doesn't make it look like Binance customers can set transaction fees lower than normal (for slower but cheaper processing in the Bitcoin network).
You may get a better answer from Binance customer support.

1 & 2. There are different fees for the different crypto exchanges(Binance, Okex, etc), so you can try different exchanges to withdraw the bitcoin. Then, if the wallet you posted here is about the web3 wallet, thus here are Unisat, and OkX wallets that most people use now. If you transfer bitcoin from one web3 wallet to another(Like from Unisat to OKX), then the fees you paid depend on the current network fee rate(maybe low or high).
3.AFAIK, the Unisat wallet is used for most web3 users, also, it's open-source.

Maybe there is no best crypto course, but in this forum(for the bitcoin), I think you should learn everything about the bitcoin first.

